# pySpark Replacing Null Value on subsets of rows

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

I have a pySpark dataframe, where I have null values that I want to replace - however the value to replace with is different for different groups.

My data looks like this (appologies, I dont have a way to past it as text):

[image]

For group A I want to replace the null values with -999;
while for group B, I want to replace the null value with 0.

Currently, I split the data into sections, then do a `df = df.fillna(-999)` .

Is there a more efficient way of doing it? in psudo-code I was thinking something along the line of `df = df.where(col('group') == A).fillna(lit(-999)).where(col('group') == B).fillna(lit(0))` but ofcourse, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Loop over all the columns you want to fill
for col in ('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'):
    # compute here conditions to fill using a value or another
    fill_a = F.col(col).isNull() & (F.col('Group') == 'A')
    fill_b = F.col(col).isNull() & (F.col('Group') == 'B')

    # Fill the column based on the different conditions 
    # using nested `when` - `otherwise`.
    #
    # Do not forget to add the last `otherwise` with the original 
    # values if none of the previous conditions have been met
    filled_col = (
        F.when(fill_a, -999)
        .otherwise(
            F.when(fill_b, 0)
            .otherwise(F.col(col))
        )
    )

    # 'overwrite' the original column with the filled column
    df = df.withColumn(col, filled_col)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option is to use [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) for each column with a "filler" column holding the replacement values:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

for c in ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']:
  df = df.withColumn(c, F.coalesce(c, F.when(F.col('group') == 'A', -999)
                                       .when(F.col('group') == 'B', 0)))
```

Comment: Thnx, but I am looking for something more dynamic than this - I have 163 columns.

Comment: @GenDemo If you still have two groups A and B but it's just the number of columns to increase, you can specify them via list comprehension, for example `[i for i in df.columns if i not in ['Client', 'Group']]`. Otherwise the for loop, even with many columns, should not be low-performant with respect to other operations.